# Why is #at:put: in GNU Smalltalk message of SmallInteger?

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

While playing around with the `Array` class in GNU Smalltalk, I was suprised that the `#at:put:` message belongs to the class `SmallInteger` instead of the class `Array` (or any other super class of `Array`). Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#at:put:` is define on `Object`. `SmallInteger` does redefine it to throw an exception since it is not indexable and any subclass while also not be indexable.

Also this is a bit tricky.

Long explanation:

1) `SmallInteger` are just translate into integer in the VM.
In fact the `SmallInteger` `a` is translate into `(a bitShift: 1) bitOr: 1` in the VM.

2) `#at:put:` is a primitive that check if the class is indexable. Indexable object are the one that can be sent `#at:put:`, `#at:` and have to be instantiate via `#new:`. This is the way to have variable instances and it is the only way. (Tangent: `OrderedCollection` is instantiating several indexable object in other to let you call `#add:` multiple time and feel like the length was infinite).

3) Knowing that if `#at:put:` was not redefine in the `SmallIntager` class, the primitive would have to first check if the object is an `SmallInteger` then check if it is indexable. This would cause you some performance penalty. And redefining the `#at:put:` on `SmallInteger` just remove the `SmallInteger` check.

Comment: Thany you for the enlightenment :-) But when #at:put: is defined in the class Object, means this that I have to redefine this message in every not-indexable class?

Comment: Nop only for does that are handle in a different way by the VM. Which will happen only if you decide to hack in the VM.